# Regex to validate a character at start and end but also multiple occurences in between

Tags: regex

I need to prevent a character / occurring in a java string at the start and end and also // anywhere with only alphanumerics allowed along with .,()?'+/

I have this `^[^/]?([\w\-\?:().,'+]/?)*[^/]$`

The main problem is that it allows invalid characters # and ## at the start.

Also tried this `^[^/]?([^\W_\-\?:().,'+]/?)*[^/]$`    to remove the _ underscore issue caused by \w

So these are invalid

```
/
A//A
A/
#
##
```

But these are valid

```
A/A
A/A.,()+A
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give it a chance to be simple.  There's no need for negated character classes (`[^X]` - "anything but X") or negative lookarounds (`(?<!X)`, `(?!X)` - "nothing, or not X").  You know exactly which characters are allowed everywhere in the string, so spell it out:

```
^[A-Za-z0-9?:().,'+-]+(?:/[A-Za-z0-9?:().,'+-]+)*$
```

You don't need to specify that the slash (`/`) can't be first, just list the characters that can.  And when a slash does appear, make sure it's followed by at least one of the other allowed characters.  And the anchors (`^` and `$`) ensure nothing else gets in.

Comment: Thanks this works too. It also solves the underscore issue with \w.

Answer (score 1):

```
^(?!/)([\w-\?:().,'+]/?)*(?<!/)$
```

You can use `lookarounds` here which `0 width assertions`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/vV1wW6/41

Comment: Use of `/?` is tricky here. It took me a while to understand it. Nice!

Answer (score 0):

you can also try this

`^[^/#]?([\w\-\?:().,'+]/?)*[^/#]$`

If you explicitly want `#` not to be include at the beginning or end, just add it in your first and last character classes `[]`

See demo https://regex101.com/r/vV1wW6/43